# CFML reCAPTCHA v3 Issue

Tags: coldfusion

Im trying to use the code I have found and its not working properly it is always saying that I am a robot do you have any idea why this will not work?
The Application.cfc has the site and secret key in it.

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<cfoutput>#application.SiteKey#</cfoutput>"></script>


<cfif ISDEFINED('FORM.FirstName')> <!--- check if form was submitted and if so run code below --->

    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=#application.SecretKey#&response=#FORM['g-recaptcha-response']#" result="Response" />
    <cfset Return = deserializeJSON(Response.FileContent) />

    <cfif Return.success IS 'true' AND Return.score GT 0.0> <!--- check if true and if score is greater than 0.5. Run code below if all good. --->

        <cfoutput>Human: #FORM.FirstName# #FORM.LastName#</cfoutput>
        <!--- you can do database entry and/or email results here --->

    <cfelse>  <!--- if not a human, do this. I usually remove the else part completely, but if you need to do something with the robot, do it here.  --->

        Most likely a robot.

    </cfif>

<cfelse> <!--- show form --->

    <form method="post" action="/contact.cfm">  <!--- submit form back to itself --->
      First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text"><br>
      Last Name: <input name="LastName" type="text"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit">
      <input name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" type="hidden" /> <!--- javascript below gives this a value from google. --->
    </form>

    <script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<cfoutput>#application.SiteKey#</cfoutput>', {action: 'homepage'})
            .then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
            });
        });
    </script>

</cfif>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP responses?  Is there an error message coming back or is it just failing the verification?        Also, when I implemented ReCaptcha, I sent the secret and the response to the API as CFHTTPPARAM form fields.  I don't know if it HAS to be done that way, but it worked for me, so, might be something to try.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code with me see if I can work with it. I've been bouncing my head on this for a little while. I'm open to new ideas to cut down on spam.

Comment: I think we'd need to see what the `Response.FileContent` is when it's not a success. At the moment that `cfelse` `Most likely a robot.` block would be hiding the information that would help to troubleshoot.

Comment: { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }

Comment: The api docs say the cfhttp method should be POST. You are using GET https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to get the form working properly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=YOUR SITE KEY"></script>
<!-- contact form demo container -->
<cfif ISDEFINED('FORM.name')> <!--- check if form was submitted and if so run code below --->

    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=#application.SecretKey#&response=#FORM['token']#" result="Response" />
    <cfset Return = deserializeJSON(Response.FileContent) />

    <cfif Return.success IS 'true' AND Return.score GT 0.5> <!--- check if true and if score is greater than 0.5. Run code below if all good. --->

       

    <cfelse>  <!--- if not a human, do this. I usually remove the else part completely, but if you need to do something with the robot, do it here.  --->

        

    </cfif>

<cfelse>
<section style="margin: 50px 20px;">
  <div style="max-width: 768px; margin: auto;">
    
    <!-- contact form -->
    <div class="card">
      <h2 class="card-header">Contact Form</h2>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form class="contact_form" method="post" action="contact.cfm">

          <!-- form fields -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 form-group">
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <!-- form message prompt -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="contact_msg" style="display: none">
                  <p>Your message was sent.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-success" name="post">
            </div>

            <!-- hidden reCaptcha token input -->
            <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('YOUR SITE KEY', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       // console.log(token);
       document.getElementById("token").value = token;
    });
    // refresh token every minute to prevent expiration
    setInterval(function(){
      grecaptcha.execute('YOUR SITE KEY', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        console.log( 'refreshed token:', token );
        document.getElementById("token").value = token;
      });
    }, 60000);

  });
</script>
</cfif>

<!-- References for the optional jQuery function to enhance end-user prompts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I passed the values to the API.    Again, just passing along code that worked, not saying this is the only way

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" result="Response">
<cfhttpparam name="secret" type="formField" value="#application.SecretKey#">
<cfhttpparam name="response" type="formField" value="#form["g-recaptcha-response"]#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Yes it is probably the POST, instead of GET, that makes the difference

Comment: I am still getting missing-input-response and a fail

Comment: Have you done a CFDUMP on the form and see everything that is coming through?

Comment: Yeah I keep getting missing input issues